# Running unit tests in TFS/VSO Build vNext using xUnit adapter

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, dnx, xunit.net, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run our xUnit tests using the xUnit test adapter in Visual Studio Online's Build vNext platform.

As stipulated in [this article](http://www.almguide.com/2015/06/running-xunit-tests-in-tfs-build-vnext/), we need to provide a custom test adapter path pointing to `xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll`.

But this package is restored by NuGet to a global packages folder, namely `C:\Users\{user}\.dnx\packages`?

How am I to reference this folder in the build step?

[image: VSO vNext Build Test Step]

We are using VS 2015 and DNX projects.

**EDIT:**

I even tried pointing to the package path DLL directly:

```
C:\Users\buildagent\.dnx\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.1.0-beta4-build1109\build\_common
```

It still did not seem to use the adapter:

```
Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\a\8ac4a4f6\Root\artifacts\bin\MyProject.UnitTest\release\dnx451\TransitApi.UnitTest.dll"  /TestAdapterPath:C:\Users\buildguest\.dnx\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.1.0-beta4-build1109\build\_common /UseVsixExtensions:true /logger:trx
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Starting test execution, please wait...
Warning: No test is available in C:\a\8ac4a4f6\Root\artifacts\bin\MyProject.UnitTest\release\dnx451\TransitApi.UnitTest.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
No results found to publish.
```

The `project.json`, if relevant:

```
"dependencies": {
  "xunit": "2.1.0-beta4-build3109",
  "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta4-build134",
  "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0-beta4-build1109"
},

"commands": {
  "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
},

"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Make a `global.json` file and put the following into it:

```
{
  "packages": "packages"
}
```

That will force your `dnu restore` to put the packages into `.\packages\`, which will hopefully solve the problem. Just specify the test adapter path as `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages\` -- you may have to specify the full assembly name, I'm not sure off the top of my head.

---

Update: I took the sample "HelloMvc" application and got it to build with xUnit tests without a `global.json`. Here's my build definition:

```
{
  "build": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Restore packages",
      "task": {
        "id": "d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "filename": "$(DNXPath)\\dnu.cmd",
        "arguments": "restore",
        "workingFolder": "",
        "failOnStandardError": "false"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Run tests",
      "task": {
        "id": "d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "filename": "$(DNXPath)\\dnx.exe",
        "arguments": "test",
        "workingFolder": "",
        "failOnStandardError": "false"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Build NuGet package",
      "task": {
        "id": "d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "filename": "$(DNXPath)\\dnu.cmd",
        "arguments": "publish",
        "workingFolder": "",
        "failOnStandardError": "false"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Publish Artifact: drop",
      "task": {
        "id": "1d341bb0-2106-458c-8422-d00bcea6512a",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "CopyRoot": "",
        "Contents": "**\\output\\*",
        "ArtifactName": "drop",
        "ArtifactType": "FilePath",
        "TargetPath": "\\\\ic-tfs-fs-01\\TFSBuilds\\$(Build.DefinitionName)\\$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      }
    }
  ],
  "options": [
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "definition": {
        "id": "7c555368-ca64-4199-add6-9ebaf0b0137d"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "multipliers": "[]",
        "parallel": "false",
        "continueOnError": "true"
      }
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "BuildConfiguration": {
      "value": "debug",
      "allowOverride": true
    },
    "BuildPlatform": {
      "value": "any cpu",
      "allowOverride": true
    },
    "DNXPath": {
      "value": "C:\\Users\\tfs-build\\.dnx\\runtimes\\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7-12335\\bin\\"
    }
  },
  "retentionRules": [
    {
      "branches": [
        "+refs/heads/*"
      ],
      "daysToKeep": 10,
      "deleteBuildRecord": true
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://ic-tfs-at-01:8080/tfs/InCycleEventsCollection/b3284707-3d86-4bc7-b321-b22aee80daca/_apis/build/Definitions/22"
    },
    "web": {
      "href": "http://ic-tfs-at-01:8080/tfs/_permalink/_build/index?collectionId=0ea6f8c1-f923-47f0-b59a-af6d452d8f7f&projectId=b3284707-3d86-4bc7-b321-b22aee80daca&definitionId=22"
    }
  },
  "buildNumberFormat": "$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)",
  "createdDate": "2015-08-12T15:34:17.887Z",
  "jobAuthorizationScope": 1,
  "jobTimeoutInMinutes": 60,
  "repository": {
    "id": "ee7584f9-ba25-4535-9b5e-5038ec6a39c7",
    "type": "TfsGit",
    "name": "AspNet5",
    "url": "http://ic-tfs-at-01:8080/tfs/InCycleEventsCollection/BTE2015/_git/AspNet5",
    "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
    "clean": "false",
    "checkoutSubmodules": true
  },
  "quality": 1,
  "authoredBy": {
    "id": "7f2b1ec7-224f-41de-b679-17e6ef28ce35",
    "displayName": "ICTFS-Admin",
    "uniqueName": "AZURE\\ICTFS-Admin",
    "url": "http://ic-tfs-at-01:8080/tfs/InCycleEventsCollection/_apis/Identities/7f2b1ec7-224f-41de-b679-17e6ef28ce35",
    "imageUrl": "http://ic-tfs-at-01:8080/tfs/InCycleEventsCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=7f2b1ec7-224f-41de-b679-17e6ef28ce35"
  },
  "queue": {
    "pool": null,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "default"
  },
  "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Definition/22",
  "type": 2,
  "revision": 6,
  "id": 22,
  "name": "ASP .NET 5 app",
  "url": "http://ic-tfs-at-01:8080/tfs/InCycleEventsCollection/b3284707-3d86-4bc7-b321-b22aee80daca/_apis/build/Definitions/22",
  "project": {
    "id": "b3284707-3d86-4bc7-b321-b22aee80daca",
    "name": "BTE2015",
    "url": "http://ic-tfs-at-01:8080/tfs/InCycleEventsCollection/_apis/projects/b3284707-3d86-4bc7-b321-b22aee80daca",
    "state": "wellFormed",
    "revision": 383343
```

I suspect that the problem is that you're trying to use the Visual Studio test adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although, this will put all packages into a local folder, which defeats the purpose of having global packages. Is there not a better solution? Can we not have just the test adapter package restored locally?

Comment: Also, would `vstest.console.exe` know to traverse the entire `packages` directory for test adapters? Do I not have to specify the exact folder where `xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll` resides?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue finding the correct path with the NUnit test adapter, here's the path I used in the Test step that ended up working for me, may work for you as well:

"$(Build.SourcesDirectory)[your path to the packages folder]\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.8.0\build\netcoreapp1.0"

The test adapter dll is in the netcoreapp1.0 folder. Also, KEEP the quotes around the path.