# Referencing package path in VSO with DNX projects

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core, azure-devops, dnx, xunit.net

I have to reference the test adapter DLL (`xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll`) in our vNext Visual Studio Online build to execute the tests.

The problem is that with the new DNX structure, packages are being restored to `C:\Users\{user}\.dnx\packages` and are not relative to the project's path anymore.

**How can I reference this location in the build?**

We are using the hosted build agent.

Comment: Please check this MSDN article to see whether it helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer for your question can be found in the following StackExchange answer: [Running unit tests in TFS/VSO Build vNext using xUnit adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870823/running-unit-tests-in-tfs-vso-build-vnext-using-xunit-adapter). Then the packages end up in a local directory and not the global .dnx cache.

...

Make a global.json file and put the following into it:

```
{
  "packages": "packages"
}
```

That will force your dnu restore to put the packages into .\packages\, which will hopefully solve the problem.